# Stop ubuntu from automatically upgrading kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I am using `ubuntu 20.04` and the default kernel version is `5.4.0-42` and `5.4.0-58`. For some reason, I have upgraded my kernel to `5.8.0-36` several days ago with the command `sudo apt install linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic`. But now the kernel version has automatically upgraded to `5.4.0-40` and I was not notified. How can I stop the automatic upgrading?

Comment: You might find [this](https://codepre.com/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-kernel-updates-disable-or-stop-linux-kernel-updates.html) reference helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you will stay with kernel branch 5.4

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

boot in the new installed kernel.

identify

```
dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|h|m]'
```

Kernel relevant packages and remove any which point to hwe-20.04 and kernel branch 5.8. like

```
linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-5.8.0-40-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-40 linux-image-5.8.0-40-generic
  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-modules-5.8.0-40-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-40-generic
```